# How to change path in Finder by entering the path manually?

Tags: macos, finder, path, filesystem

It seems that by default there is no way to enter a whole path in the Finder, so instead one should traverse through all the tree to get somewhere deep in the filesystem. Is there anyway to overcome this problem? If there is no GUI for it in the Finder maybe launching it from the command line with the path? Something like:

```
finder /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/
```

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Finder has a menu item found under Go ("Go to Folder…") where you can type a full path.

The <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> keyboard shortcut makes it handy to summon. This short cut works in the file open and save dialog as well.

[image: Finder Go > Go to Folder...]

Tab file path completion works in this window as does pasting words or a path for a file or network share.

The `open` command works to do this from the command line.

```
open /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/
```

Comment: Is there a way to click on the path in finder and insert the path string right there, as in Windows Explorer?

Comment: no @Meglio you have to paste in the go to dialog that pops up.

Comment: Brilliant!  You can summon it in the GUI of other applications when you want to "Open File"..  Too bad this is a quick key and not built into the Finder.  Fortunately G for go is easy to remember so maybe we are better off just remembering that.

Comment: Making it impossible to *paste* the path is extremely low usability for Power Users. And so much worse than Windows!

Comment: Shift command g then command v pastes the path @sophros

Comment: Thank you @bmike. However, I am wondering why it is a different command than Ctrl + V? Is there a different command per each entry box? :P Event though it is possible, it is still low usability as it is breaking an important convention.

Comment: I'm going to edit that - it's simply command-v @sophros control v isn't a Mac paste command unless you change the defaults (which opens up lots of ways people can get what they want out of keyboard shortcuts)

Answer (score 20):

The command line version would be:

```
open -R /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/
```

or just:

```
open /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/
```

depending on you want to go inside the folder or reveal the folder in finder.

Answer (score 8):

Use Spotlight Search (which can be opened quickly with `Command + Space` or sometimes a dedicated key like ).  It has been around since Mac OSX 10.4 Tiger.

Just type or paste the full path into the Spotlight Search box.  Even a partial folder and/or file name can also reveal the destination, albeit there might be a long list of matches to weed through.

Comment: Going to path using Spotlight is also cool! Thank you!