# Upgraded from High Sierra to Catalina, lost my Safari session with all my open windows and tabs. Is there any way to recover them?

Tags: safari, time-machine, catalina, tabs, bookmarks

I had been staying on High Sierra for a long time, with Safari 13 I think, the last version that worked with High Sierra. I just upgraded to Catalina and then immediately upgraded Safari to 15.6.1. Everything went fine until a launched Safari and found I'd lost everything I had open.

I tend to keep a lot of browser windows and tabs open. I minimize the ones that I'm not actively using. If I force-quit Safari when I want to close it, I find on relaunch it only loads the webpages that are open, the minimized ones don't load until I maximize them. Because of this, I could have lots of windows without hurting my computer's performance too much. I found this an easier way to organize stuff I wanted to revisit and finish reading later, rather than having to use bookmarks which require constantly going through menus to create and delete them which is a much slower process.

This time, after the updates, when I launched Safari I only got one blank window. I tried "Reopen All Windows from Last Session", but all that did was open a bunch of blank windows with only one tab saying "untitled". I tried it several times, adblockers on and off etc, I just got hundreds of blank untitled Safari windows open.

I have a Time Machine backup from before the update. (Also a backup disk image made with SuperDuper.) I can't restore from that and re-do the update to try again because I did a bunch of work organizing and deleting files after the update, and that would be lost. Is there any to transfer my session from a backup to my new computer?
I found one discussion here: [Where does Safari store the open tabs?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/374099/where-does-safari-store-the-open-tabs) that discusses the session info being stored differently in Safari 13 and 15, and how do do what I'm asking with either one. But it doesn't say how to transfer a session from 13 *to* 15 or if that's possible.

The only way I can think of is:

- create a bootable hard drive or USB thumb drive from one of my backups before the OS update
- boot off of that volume-this will run slow compared to running off the internal SSD, making things even more tedious
- launch Safari and reopen all windows, and create a bookmark folder with the tabs from each window
- export my bookmark collection onto a thumb drive
- boot from my internal SSD with Catalina, lauch Safari and import the bookmarks I created.

That might work, but it would be incredibly tedious and probably take many hours. Is there any more direct way to do it? I had windows open going back months, with tabs on topics I was researching and so forth. Yes, I know I'm an idiot for browsing this way and I should find a different way to organize my reading, but in the meantime I really want to get those tabs back. Can anyone think of a more efficient way to do it?