# Open /dev in Finder

Tags: macos, finder, catalina, unix

Is it possible to open the `/dev/` directory in Finder? If not why?  Is it on some kind of exclude list?

I would like to use a GUI to list the files there on macOS Catalina.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Looking at what Finder **(1)** does using Hopper reveals that there are indeed hard-coded exclusion paths, and it rewrites paths starting with `/dev/` to `/`.

[image]

You can verify this by pressing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and entering a path starting with `/dev/` -- i.e. `/dev/foo`. You'll be presented with `/`.

**(1)** Located at `/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder`.

Comment: Please add why it doesn't make much sense to open this "folder" with the Finder (or ForkLift)!  [Mac OS X for Unix Geeks: The /dev Directory](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mac-os-x/0596003560/apas01s05.html), [Understanding the /dev directory](http://www.linux-databook.info/?page_id=5108)

Comment: Spotlight is hands off here as well - `mdls` returns no results for that folder. Perhaps not fans of the ouroboros?

Comment: God, that's so cool that you can just open up the binary like that, I need to learn how to use Hopper. How easy would it be for you to export a modified binary without those exclusions?

Comment: @Wowfunhappy The system almost certainly won't run a Finder that's not signed by Apple, so you'd have to disable those security measures. You can still access `/dev` and `/private` using Terminal.

Comment: @19h I can't find this in Hopper. Do you remember how you located it?

Answer (score 6):

It’s not clear if Finder has a special case to avoid this folder, but no - it doesn't want to show that folder.

Normally, I would try the go to functionality using a key shortcut of shift-command-G (or use the pointer and the go menu of Finder) and type in /dev

[How to change path in Finder by entering the path manually?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43291/how-to-change-path-in-finder-by-entering-the-path-manually)

Now, most unix directories are hidden, so toggle hidden files with shift-command-. (period) and you will see it's notably absent.

I’ll keep poking at this, but for now, my Catalina Macs don’t want to show you this in Finder.

A possible solution is to use [ForkLift](https://binarynights.com/).

- Make sure to grant it full disk access in system preferences for this app when it asks or after you run it once.
- Make sure it's showing hidden files
- /dev shows up like a mounted drive at the root directory

Comment: I get: "The folder can't be found." https://imgur.com/a/4eLsdpk

Comment: Did you try that, Mike? `/dev` opens `/Developer`, `/dev/` just error-beeps (on Mojave at least).

Comment: @bmike /dev is the devices folder with block and character devices like disk0 or ttyp0

Comment: Aah, Tom. If you can get to /usr/local and not /dev that implies your user that runs finder doesn’t have permission. Try looking at /

Comment: Any user has permission to browse `/dev`, a lot of things wouldn't work otherwise on a Unix system.

Comment: Sorry for posting part and coming back for the edit. I’ve changed it to no, and trying this doesn’t work.

Comment: `dr-xr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  8226 Apr  4 09:52 /dev`

Comment: Exactly. Even with hidden files turned on I'm not seeing `/dev`, but inside the Terminal, *not* using root, I can. Doesn't really makes sense to me. I don't want to change any permissions. If it's not possible, so be it :D

Comment: Yeah - I wonder if ForkLift or another finder replacement is needed .... I was totally wrong on the yes and the Unix  permissions

Comment: @bmike Indeed. Using ForkLift you can view it. Wow. Not really a solution, since I won't be switching, but thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Tom Thanks for the great question, I learned finder has blind spots that don't make sense overall in the generic permissions model. Some people will learn about hidden files through this - sounds like you had a deeper question than I suspected at first.