# Can I find the source code for Grapher?

Tags: macos, open-source, grapher

[Grapher](https://support.apple.com/guide/grapher/welcome-gcalb3dec608/mac) is an application that is installed on macOS by default. Can I find its source code, or is it proprietary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grapher is not an open-source app and you can not find its source code publicly.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/388101/open-dev-in-finder "hopper" can be used though

Comment: Is there any way to get it, even if not from the internet?

Comment: Is it at least possible to know how it was written