# How to go to arbitrary folder in Finder?

Tags: macos, finder

Sometimes when I open Finder it shows me some folder which I can't change. In Windows I would change folder path in address bar, but here I don't see anything like this. It shows me some Favourites but this is not what I want

[image]

Comment: Many [good answers here as well](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/43291/5472).

Answer (score 3):

In **Finder** you can press **⇧⌘G** to bring up the **Go to the folder:** *sheet*.

Or from the **Go** *menu*, click: **Go to Folder…**

Where you can either copy and paste a *folder pathname*, or type it manually, then clicked the **Go** *button* or press **enter**.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a single default to show in new Finder Windows.

Finder menu > Preferences…

[image]

Otherwise, use  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>G</kbd>   for Go To… or set common locations into your sidebar, by drag & drop.

Answer (score 0):

Also in the Finder menu > Preferences under Sidebar you can select what shows us as shortcuts on the left side of the Finder window. Helpful to turn on is your home directory (if you often need to get to items there) or your computer, which shows a few of all the storage attached to the computer.

You can also drag folders to the Favorites section of the sidebar directly. These become shortcuts to the folder available in any Finder window (and also in standard "Open" and "Save" dialogs.